# How can I fix "SyntaxError: invalid error" for function is_prime?

Tags: python-3.x, primes

## There is a syntax error in line 3. I'm unsure of how to correct the error.

Write a python function is_prime() which takes one integer as an argument and returns True or False (boolean values). If the integer argument is a prime number, it should return True. If not a prime number, it should return False. Printing should happen after evaluating the return value of the function.

Message: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
def is_prime(n):   
    n = (int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if n > 1:
            for n in range(2,int(n/2)+1):
                    if (n % j) == 0:
                            print("The number is not a prime number")
                            break
            else:
               print(n, "is a prime number")
    else:
       print(n, "is not a prime number")
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Images of code are totally useless here. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem, along with the **complete, exact error message** that you're getting. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see that screen from here. You're asking us to help you solve a problem, so it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing the relevant information that you have available.

Comment: If you can provide an example of how to input a question, that would be helpful. This was my first time and I was having difficulty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you observe closely, the 5th line has two parenthesis set required.

- One for `int()`
- The other for `input()`

But you only provided one closing bracket. The solution would be to add one more closing parenthesis :)

Something like this:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a number"))
```

Comment: Thank you! The worked but there is now another syntax error in line 3.